# Access Hyper-V guest with no network access

Tags: vpn, hyper-v

I am currently running a VM on VMWare which needs to connect to a customer VPN which disables all other network adapters when it is active. Using VMWare, I can connect using it's built in VNC Server while the VM is connected but obviously cannot retrieve files from the network from the VM, this is a major inconvenience for us.

We are starting to evaluate Hyper-V as a replacement because it is more scriptable on the free version and I know that I can achieve this same effect using the Connect function in Hyper-V Manager.

My question is, is there any way to give a guest VM direct access to files on the host without using anything that would be broken by a disabled network connection so we can still transfer files to and from the VPN while it is connected to the customer's VPN.

Being able to do this would seal the deal for Hyper-V.

Comment: Hyper-V has extensions that allows you to drop and drag files from/to the virtual machine.  If the virtual machine is disconnected from the "network" you would run into a problem if your sharing the files through the network but would not effect the file sharing of Hyper-v

Comment: I've found plenty of mention of drag and drop in VPC but everything I can find suggests this isn't possible in Hyper-V, could you provide a link?

Comment: I don't have a link. Doing a google search on the subject Hyper-V apparently removed the drag and drop feature I used in the past in previous iternations of the software. Of course you can also attach a VHD within Windows 7 and simply transfer the files through Windows Explorer with either Hyper-V or VMWare as a solution

Comment: I'm thinking use hot-swap VHD, drop it from the VM, mount to the host and share, copy over my files then reverse the process to hot-add it. Still hoping someone has an easier solution though...

Comment: Pretty easy in my eyes based on your requirements